How to get string value of a xrpl4j generated private key?
I haven't been able to find any examples of how to convert the bytes of the private key to get the actual string value. Any help would be appreciated. Note this is Java code based off the xrpl4j library
KeyPair randomKeyPair = Seed.ed25519Seed().deriveKeyPair();

PublicKey publicKey = randomKeyPair.publicKey();
PrivateKey privateKey = randomKeyPair.privateKey();

byte[] byteArray = privateKey.naturalBytes().toByteArray();

String value = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

System.out.println("publicKey: " + publicKey.deriveAddress());
System.out.println("privateKey: " + value);

// output

publicKey: rZPmCswFy1WVSXnatLpnUnwLpt9Xi4oqF
privateKey: ?a'c~???!??,??????w???????+??



After reading: Like the seed, the private key is secret information, so you must protect it very carefully., do you really need it ?

Yes for a paper wallet generator.
